# fragment returning the view before the end of thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, http, asynchronous

I am trying to put a progressDialog in my fragment so my app feels smoother between each actions. The problem that I have is that the main thread is returning the view before the async thread has modified it. I was doing a Thread.join() before switching to this methode.

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle args) {
    mLLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity()); 
    mLLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    mLLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    mScroll = new ScrollView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mScroll.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    mScroll.addView(mLLayout);

    new AsyncCaller().execute();

    return mScroll;
}

private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ProgressDialog nDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        //Doing http requests and modifying views
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //this method will be running on UI thread

        nDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
...
}
```

I cant find a solution without blocking the main thread and by the same way not seeing the progressDialog at all and having a big lag instead. Also, I never saw my code go into "onPostExecute()".

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: A thread behaves asynchronously so your Fragment is going to continue on and return the view no matter what.  This is expected and this is exactly what should happen.  You can't assume that a thread will run immediately or end in a reasonable time.  There's also no reason to use Thread.join() when using AsyncTask.

Comment: yea i know all that, and i was using Thread.join() BEFORE switching to async. What I am looking for is to find a way to have all the data before returning the view without blocking the main thread.

Comment: so all you want to do is show the pd in the main activity while your background activity is calculating its stuff?

Comment: Yes, and finding a way to do it before returning the view :/

Comment: You can't.  You have to make the logic such that you won't even try to show the fragment until the data is loaded or prevent the user from interacting with it in some way.  What happens if connection is lost before data is finished?  What if the data is corrupted?  What happens if it takes 5 minutes to download?

Comment: ok, then is there a way to display the ProgressDialog at the same time has my other thread running (with the main thread waiting for it to finish this time)

Answer (score 0):

Striaght from an app i've done, this code should help:

```
ProgressBar mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
private float mProgressStatus = 0;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private void startProgressBar()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (mProgressStatus < 100)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mProgressStatus += 1.3;
                mHandler.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        mProgress.setProgress((int) mProgressStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: The problem is not to show the loading progress, it's to do it before returning the view of the fragment. I don't know if there is a way to do it like im doing. Maybe im just doing it wrong, but I have no other idea.